# How to compare Local Group Policy of two distinct Windows Server 2016 machines?

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2016

I want to compare group policies of two different machines, what is the proper way to do this?

From what I researched I found how to [apply the same GP on another machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/525175/how-can-i-apply-local-group-policy-to-multiple-computers)
**,But I want to see what policies were set - not just copy it.**

I also found that you can `Export list...` of group policies using the *Local Group Policy Editor* (`gpedit.msc`)
to a text file, which seems to be the best option, but it allows me to only export the settings *Administrative Templates* of a user/computer and not the whole policies.

Is there an option to export / backup to a readable file the whole GP?

*Can't use [Group Policy PowerShell Cmdlets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-r2-and-2008/ee461027(v=technet.10))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Local Group Policy Utility, which is part of the Security Compliance Toolkit.

Create a backup: `lgpo.exe /b x:\Temp /n "LGPO Backup"`

Parse the policy to a text file: `lgpo.exe /parse /m x:\Temp\{xxx}\DomainSysvol\GPO\Machine\registry.pol >> x:\Temp\lgpo.txt`

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55319

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-security-configuration-framework/security-compliance-toolkit-10